# Are there any luggage lockers at Roma Termini?

Tags: luggage-storage, rome

I'll be in Rome just over a day and I don't want to bring my carry-on bag with me everywhere. Are there any luggage lockers at Roma Termini where I can leave my luggage for a few hours? I'll be departing from Roma Termini by train, and also arriving there so it would be very convinient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Italia Rail’s Rome Termini Station guide https://www.italiarail.com/train-station/rome-termini-train-station the floor below the platform level is where you'll find the KiPoint left luggage facility https://www.romatermini.com/en/service/detail/left-luggage

A quick internet search shows there are numerous luggage storage facilities close to the station eg LuggageHero https://luggagehero.com/rome/roma-termini/

Comment: I ended up using the [Capital Luggage Deposit](https://maps.app.goo.gl/o8TUb89BJ4VndaZP8) just next to the station.